# What address should we use for a standard UK visitor visa if we live off-grid and don't have an official address?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

It's a bit of a complicated question. What address should we use for our visitor application to the UK? We are a married couple with no intention to stay in the UK. We live in Colombia and the UK national among us has a 3-year visa to stay in Colombia.

So basically we have land here. We don't have the "official" documents for it right now because it was a friendly transaction, where we bought a parcel from a friend's big plot. We paid him for the land and only have a simple contract for it. Most of the land in that area is done with basic contracts rather than title deeds, because it is a farming region and not so "modern".

Do we put that as our address? Or the families address which, is our "official" one? Thoughts?

Comment: We live on the land that is mentioned and are growing food/building a house there. Thanks

Comment: But without a document to prove it? It might be better to just put the official address right?? Really stuck on this one!

Comment: We live completely off-grid. There is no mail :(

Comment: Your passport with visa, if approved, will be delivered to you by mail or courier...to where?

Comment: If you buy construction supplies for your house, do you have them delivered? If so, what location do you give the supplier?

Comment: If the process is similar to that in Cuba, it’s likely that you’ll have to either collect your passport from the local embassy where you have your biometric appointment, or you can authorise someone to collect it for you. In which case the address you use only matters if it has to be verified by the local embassy as part of processing the application.

Comment: @user16259 You don’t - you probably have to organise pick up / delivery yourself.

Comment: How does the government identify the land parcel?  Or does nobody believe you own the land except for that piece of paper?